# How to set the htmlattributes cleanly on a razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set up a text area on an MVC razor page like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Description)
```

But I have no idea of a tidy way to set the htmlattributes on the overload for this method on the page. Or perhaps I can do it on the model?

Knowing how to do it both ways would be really nice :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like,

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Description, new { yourattribute = "Hello" })
```

This is an anonymous type. If you need to use language keywords, like `class`, escape it with an @:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Description, new { @class = "yourCSSclass", yourattribute = "Hello" })
```

Comment: @Exitos - Out of the box, no I don't believe it is possible.